# Serving three tomcat instances on the same linux machine by one apache-http-server

Tags: dns, apache-http-server, port-forwarding, localhost, tomcat

I am trying to serve three tomcat instances on the same linux machine by one apache-http-server. App1 on tomcat listening to 8080, App2 listening to 8081 and App3 on 8082. There should be three websites to hit them. for App1 website.domain.com/App1.  for App2 website.domain.com/App2. for App3 website.domain.com/App3.

Right now the vhosts.conf, looks like following. which I think is a bit messy. It is not working as well. Could you please help me with this.

[root@servername conf.d]# more vhosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName website.domain.com/App1

ProxyRequests On
    ProxyPass / http:// localhost:8081/App1/
    ProxyPassReverse / http:// localhost:8081/App1/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName website.domain.com/App2

ProxyRequests On
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8081/App2/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8081/App2/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName website.domain.com/App2

ProxyRequests On
    ProxyPass / http:// localhost:8082/App2/
    ProxyPassReverse / http:// localhost:8082/App2/
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}$1
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
  SSLEngine on
  ServerName %{HTTP_HOST}
  ServerAlias *.domain.com

  Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000;"
  Header always set X-Frame-Options DENY
  Header edit Set-Cookie ^(.*)$ $1;HttpOnly;Secure
  RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto https
  RequestHeader set Front-End-Https "On"

  LogLevel warn
  ErrorLog logs/ssl_error_log
  TransferLog logs/ssl_access_log
  CustomLog logs/ssl_request_log "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"

  ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain localhost %{HTTP_HOST}
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  #ProxyRequests off
  RequestHeader unset Origin

  ProxyPass / http:// localhost:8080/

  ProxyPassReverse / http:// localhost:8080/
  ProxyPass / http:// localhost:8081/
  ProxyPassReverse /  http://localhost:8081/
  ProxyPass / http:// localhost:8082/
  ProxyPassReverse / http:// localhost:8082/
```

Answer (score 0):

A servername is a domain name, not URL.

For port 80 you only want 1 virtualhost block with the 3 pairs of Proxypass and ProxypassRevetse rules.

The format of your rules should include the path like:

```
  ProxyPass /app1 http://localhost:8082/
  ProxyPassReverse /app1 http://localhost:8082/
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply. I have now changed it inside one block and the welcome page of tomcat is loading. But when I try to hit the application. It says, 
Not Found.
The requested URL /app1 was not found on this server. tomcat and the applications are deployed.

Comment: What is the Tomcat URL to access the app? (You may need to fiddle with the right side of the Proxypass+proxypassreverse lines with the appropriate URL path?